# How to vaildate a subscriber has uploaded a thumbnail using javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, thumbnails

I have this code in my child theme template submit_video.php.  I want to validate that the subscriber has uploaded a thumbnail or they CANNOT publish a video.  Here is the code used for upload..I have tried several things already.  I am just a beginner in JS..This is the code to Upload a thumbnail..I just cant figure out how to validate this now, with JS or other code per se' (PHP)

```
<!--UploadThumbnail-->
<div class="col-12 mb-2">
    <label class="label-sm qs-font-weight-medium bm_cya_form_label">
    <?php esc_html_e('Upload Thumbnail', 'betube') ?> :
    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    <span class="small"><?php esc_html_e('Best image size is 850x550px', 'betube') ?></span>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="btp_thumbnail" accept="image/*">
    </div>
    <!--UploadThumbnail-->
```

Any help would be appreciated..Thanks in Advance!

I tried this generic code changing names etc. No go and couldn't figure it out

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function for validating the input file element. Just set the attribute `required` on the element. THe form will only submit if it is valid meaning that all required form fields in the form are valid.

About the naming. In a form you should always have a name attribute on each form field and the form itself. You can either use the dot syntax (`document.forms.uploadthumbnail`) or the "array" syntax (`document.forms['uploadthumbnail']`). In the case of the file input with the name `upload_attachment[]` you need to use the array syntax because of the square brackets in the name: `document.forms.uploadthumbnail['upload_attachment[]']`.

```js
document.uploadthumbnail.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  console.log('You are uploading',form['upload_attachment[]'].files.length, 'file');
});
```

```html
<form name="uploadthumbnail">
  <!--UploadThumbnail-->
  <div class="col-12 mb-2">
    <label class="label-sm qs-font-weight-medium bm_cya_form_label">Upload Thumbnail<span class="text-danger">*</span> 
      <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" accept="image/*" required>
    </label>
  </div>
  <!--UploadThumbnail-->
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```